# how to find on which day the first of a month, given by user, in a year, given by user, falls in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to write a program that asks the user to enter a month and year and that prints out the day on which the first day of the month falls.

Output:

```
Enter the month: March  
Enter the year: 2012 
The 1st of March 2012 is a Thursday.
```

is there a way to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `calendar` library. `calendar.weekday(year, month, day)` return the day of the week.

Answer (score 0):

The [datetime libary](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#module-datetime) will problaly enable you do what you're trying to achieve.

The function [date.weekday](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.weekday) gives you out the day in form of an integer(Monday = 0, Sunday = 6)